# Append a link to all timecodes (Like YouTube)

Tags: wordpress, youtube, mediaelement, skip, timecodes

i want to find all timecodes in my content area and build a simple link around it, so i can jump to a specific timecode on my Wordpress Mediaelement.

How can I do this so it finally looks like:

```
<div class="timecodes">
  <li>
    **<a class="go-to-time">**15:30**</a>** "Title"
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: sadly not. I don't know how i can detect all strings in that timecode-format "mm:ss". Then it would be super easy i think, to build the class around it :(

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself, here is my solution:

```
var str=document.getElementById("timecodes").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/[0-9][0-9][:][0-9][0-9]/gi,function myFunction(x){return "<a class='go-to-time'>" + x + "</a>";});
document.getElementById("timecodes").innerHTML=n;
```